# Authentication for REST Services from IOS Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, rest, restful-authentication

I have a rest service,(the service URL is a dummy one & doesn't work)

http://www.testDomain.com/authenticate/

which is username and password authenticated

how do i call this rest service from my application?

The following is the code which i had written in order to consume this REST service(Earlier this service wasn't user name & password authenticated).

> NSString *testUrl=@"http://www.testDomain.com/authenticate/";

```
        //NSString *testUrl=@"http://www.testDomain.com/authenticate/";

        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init]autorelease];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:testUrl]];
        [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        //[request addValue:<#(NSString *)value#> forHTTPHeaderField:<#(NSString *)field#>]
        [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```

Comment: The link is unreachable, is it protected by basic authentication?

Comment: @how do i complete this basic authentication process from my IOS application (i ve the username & password)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways:
unsecured:
ask user for username and pass and send url as http://username:pass@....

support NSUrlConnection delegate:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSString *user = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%s%@", 'a', "a", @"a"];
    NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%s%@", 'a', "a", @"a"];

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user
                                                             password:password
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}
```

for u service is better using first way, bcd u anyway not protect link by ssl and somebody smart can sniff all u users and passwords :)
p.s. interesting strings is protect from read login/pass from code...